# How to include javax.jms.* in Intellij?

Tags: java

I can't seem to get this to work in a regular Java project. Does this only work with Maven?

I'm trying to implement the [Message interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) for a class like so...

```
public class Test implements Message {
}
```

I include the following import statement at the top of my code:

```
javax.jms.*
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDEzg.png)

Would I include something like the following in one of the XML files?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
<artifactId>jms</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not in a Maven project, you have to tell IntelliJ that your code needs the *jms* library.

To do so, open your project/module settings and under libraries add it.

---

Depending on what you want to do with this project, consider using Maven. Unless this is a "toy project", chances are high that you'll benefit from a proper dependency manager as Maven.

Comment: Hey how would you add the jms library in a Maven project? This doesn't work for me in there either.

Comment: In Maven, you'd have to add the piece of XML you put in your question in the `pom.xml` file.